# Solved -Failed to read a b58check_encoding data - Tezos Signer

Tags: tezos-client, error, tezos-signer, base58

I'm doing everything as directed by this tutorial.

https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor/wiki/How-to-use-tezos-signer

```
./tezos-signer import secret key teste2019 encrypted:edesk1d3bvnPdjzqseEpKyv5NfhJfHcuCn2R3Lxfn3a8HAe9LjPn9iKzxX3iX1NdykCfYGUUGEXcoy8KVpEPApwzSf8hwjW24bMeBbCADL2JNQAD7pA9oaL
./tezos-signer launch socket signer -a 127.0.0.1 -p 22000 -W
```

But when I run this command

```
tezos-client import secret key teste2019  tcp://127.0.0.1:22000/tz1aiUfds6dJZWwNyJERiN6NDSPWJZJQ1TbL -f
```

I get this error:

```
Error:
  Cannot parse the key uri: tcp://127.0.0.1:22000/edpktoahiHd2E8oXAJqfefDJ98PMe3Whkw5UHDBFjs5KvgtqZuDNMn
  Failed to read a b58check_encoding data (Signature.Public_key_hash): "edpktoahiHd2E8oXAJqfefDJ98PMe3Whkw5UHDBF
js5KvgtqZuDNMn"
```

What am I doing wrong?